# grafana ec2-instance filter by tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set up a  var template in grafana that would allow me to only show ec2 instances with specific ec2 tags.  I did find

`ec2_instance_attribute(us-east-1, InstanceId, {"tag:app": ["$application"]})`

on a grafana community site and i changed it to

`ec2_instance_attribute(us-west-2, InstanceId, {"tag:ENV": ["Prod"]})`

The tags based off of my ec2 instance tags is and i keep getting a metric error. I tried removing the brackets and tweaking and still can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to create this using this method or another one i haven't thought of?

Answer (score -2):

Your expression should be working. But I had this error also, due to a missing AWS Policy permission. This might be the case for you as well AWS has a default Policy to read CloudWatch data: "CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess ", but creating my own policy as a copy of "CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess" and adding "ec2:DescribeTags" and "ec2:DescribeInstances" made this work for me.

The above answer might be only applicable when you control your access via Roles with Policies.